# Objective-C program falling on scrolling UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception

Hi i made an application which has tableview, it works fine but now it starts falling when i scroll it.It always scroll nearly 5-10 percent of content, so if i use it on table whit 200 data it scroll 10-20 but whit larger data it shows larger data but then it falls.Can U help me why?or where i have to find the problem?
thanks

the error message:

```
2011-02-09 13:23:13.631 NavTest[2277:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fa0be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010f55c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f59628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f5959a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   Foundation                          0x000bf406 mutateError + 156
    5   NavTest                             0x0000c13a -[TretiViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] + 487
    6   NavTest                             0x0000cb22 -[TretiViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 191
    7   UIKit                               0x003467fa -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    8   UIKit                               0x0033c77f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x00351450 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    10  UIKit                               0x00349538 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01e5e451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01e5e17c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01e5737c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01e570d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01e877d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f81fbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00f170e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00edfbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00edf240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00edf161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x018d5268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x018d532d GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002e142e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  NavTest                             0x0000257c main + 102
    25  NavTest                             0x0000250d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application crashes at [NSCFString appendString:]: nil.Just go through your code,where you are using appendstring function.In that point,you are getting nil,hence the application is crashing.You can also debug your code,i hope you will get solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your `-configureCell:atIndexPath:` method, you use the `-appendString:` method somewhere. It fails, if the argument passed to the function is nil. Fix that and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it crashed at append i have to use some test before something like this helped me.
it happens when the collumn in databsetable is empty it returns NIL not @"" as I was expecting

```
if([[selectedObject valueForKey:@"SOMEDATABASEENTRY"] description]!=nil){
         [pom appendString:[[selectedObject valueForKey:@"SOMEDATABASEENTRY"] description]];}
```

Thanks for answers